# what is sitemaps how do i create this

Tags: html, xml

i tried to add my domain to `google, bing` and other search engine but failed
it ask for sitemaps but i dont know anything about `xml` and how do i create this con someone help me or guide me how to do this

a simple example please
i got this from online generator is this site map or what

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<!-- created with Free Online Sitemap Generator www.xml-sitemaps.com -->

<url>
  <loc>http://www.blogtom.com/</loc>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.blogtom.com/blog/</loc>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.blogtom.com/pages/WI00001.php</loc>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.blogtom.com/pages/TT00001.php</loc>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.blogtom.com/pages/GA00001.php</loc>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.blogtom.com/pages/WI00004.php</loc>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.blogtom.com/pages/AP0001.php</loc>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.blogtom.com/pages/GA00002.php</loc>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.blogtom.com/pages/TT00002.php</loc>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.blogtom.com/pages/DAT0001.php</loc>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.blogtom.com/pages/GA00004.php</loc>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.blogtom.com/pages/GA00005.php</loc>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.blogtom.com/pages/WI00002.php</loc>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.blogtom.com/pages/WI00003.php</loc>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.blogtom.com/pages/DE00001.php</loc>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.blogtom.com/pages/GA00003.php</loc>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.blogtom.com/index.php</loc>
</url>
</urlset>
```

i found various online generator can i use that or what guide me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely use any web generator. A good one I found is:

https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/

Or really any of the ones you found are probably ok.

A sitemap is helpful for Google and Bing to navigate your site, however, it isn't compulsory. Even Google mentions that they will probably be fine without one (https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156184?hl=en), however, it is always best practice to include one.

I hope I have been of help, if you need more information please ask.